# Script to Find CPP Macro Object and Replace Token

Tags: c++, bash, perl, c-preprocessor

Okay, I have tried to do this in Perl and have had little to no success...

Inside of a .cpp file I have the following text...

```
#define VARIABLE_A    32
```

And I wish to replace this with some other number

```
#define VARIABLE_A    123
```

I would like to be able to run this through my command-line such as:

```
change_variable_a 123
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this? BASH or Perl preferred.

The code I have now is garbage. I am going about it completely wrong trying to pass parameters through a bash script into a perl one-liner.

Okay here is what I have.

```
 perl -MPOSIX -pe's/(\d+)/@ARGV[0]/e if /define\s+VARIABLE_A\s+\d+/' file.h > file.h.2
 mv -f file.h.2 file.h
```

Comment: _" I am too embarrased to post this code."_ Well, no fix available then. We're not a free code writing service, sorry.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I am coming off that way, aren't I? At any rate I am hoping there is some very easy way to do this, some sort of regex magick that does exactly this sort of thing for C++ #define since I must not be the first person to want to configure preprocessors via command-line. I have posted the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you recompile, you can use the -D option to set a value on the command line (at least in gcc and clang; presumably others).  So the simplest solution is to just define VARIABLE_A on the command line.

```
gcc -D VARIABLE_A=123 file.cc
```

If you want to have a default, you just need to have something in your code to define VARIABLE_A when it hasn't been set on the command line.

```
#ifndef VARIABLE_A
#define VARIABLE_A 32
#endif
```

Comment: This is useful and helpful, unfortunately not an option for myself on this particular project due to the build process not being within my control to change.

Comment: What aspects of the project do you have the ability to change?  Can you move the `#define VARIABLE_A` into a header file by itself, and replace the original define with an include?  Then at least you just have to replace a one-line file to change VARIABLE_A.

Comment: Impossible; it is complicated, I will spare you the details. What if I re-phrase this problem and remove the fact that is inside a cpp file? As in I have "define bar 67" inside of a file and I wish to have a script that allows me to replace this with "define bar 72" upon running "change_bar 72".

Comment: For what it's worth, I've noticed that giving more details will often let people find solutions that you weren't expecting.  That said, it sounds like you have access to that one file and only that file, so you need to change just that line, and no other.  If so, the fact this is in C++ is not actually critical, and what you really want is a targeted search-and-replace script that you can run from the command line.  You might want to just use sed.

Comment: Aye, I am being very general simply because much of the work is such that I could get into some trouble for posting any hint of source code on the Internet. Regardless, sed looks like it will work nicely, and for this I thank you kindly. I'll be sure to include the solution I ended up using once I have it working.

Answer (score 1):

This might answer your question in general: [Override macro from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483166/override-macro-from-the-command-line)

But, one thing you probably can do is to define

```
#define VARIABLE_A argument
int argument;
```

Then read argument from the command line.

Comment: Essentially reading from command line is not what is desired here. I will be recompiling regardless and simply need to change the configuration.