# How to fix "SOME_MACRO redefined" error in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, autoconf

I'm trying to compile an app from source, managed with Autoconf et al. The configure script independently passes the macro `-DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1` to the preprocessor, but unfortunately `HAVE_STDLIB_H` has been already (maybe poorly) defined somewhere deep into another part of the code (with `#define HAVE_STDLIB_H`).

Is there a way to undefine, override or simply get rid of that macro generated by the configure script, without touching the source code?

(EDIT: I don't know if this is a real duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483166), because here I'm working with the configure script instead of the "bare" gcc command line parameters.)

Comment: Do both macros serve the same purpose or is this deeply-hidden macro really just there out of pristine stupidity/imprudence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override macro from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483166/override-macro-from-the-command-line)

Comment: D you consider the configure script to be a s "source code" ?

Comment: No it is not possible, you should touch the code somewhere, either the script or whatever.

Comment: @cad unfortunately I don't know. I hope for the former :)